# How to add seconds to a date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame `df`, where `time` is given in `seconds` (from the beginning of the day)

```
df["time"]

0 43200 
1 43240 
2 43280
3 43320
```

`43200` corresponds to `12:00:00`

How can I add a date (2019-07-21) to df["time"], so that the result is

```
df["time"]

0 2019-07-21 12:00:00 
1 2019-07-21 12:00:40 
2 2019-07-21 12:01:20
3 2019-07-21 12:02:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with `unit` and `origin` parameters:

```
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"], unit='s', origin='2019-07-21')
print (df)
                 time
0 2019-07-21 12:00:00
1 2019-07-21 12:00:40
2 2019-07-21 12:01:20
3 2019-07-21 12:02:00
```

Comment: Thank you. Someone downgraded my question and your solution, strange. I upgraded your result which is exactly what I need.